# I am a beginning php and i have encountered a wierd thing

Tags: php

I have written the following html and php file

html file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<span>
</span>
<form id="login"action="login.php"method="post">
<input type="text"name="user">
<input type="submit"value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

php file :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST[‘user’]))
{
echo 'true';
}
else
{
echo "false";
}
?>
```

Please help even if there is a value it shows false.I dont know why.Thanks all help appreciated

Comment: This might just be the way SO has formatted it but are there actually spaces between the HTML attributes (eg "login"action=)?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
isset($_POST[‘user’])
```

To:

```
isset($_POST["user"])
```

Or:

```
isset($_POST['user'])
```

Comment: Thanks It worked but in the book it was written like this in the book is it wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['user']))
{
echo 'true';
}
else
{
echo 'false';
}
?>
```

And use `!empty` better.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put a space between attributes
2. Use apostrophes or quotes around strings, not ticks: `$_POST[‘user’]` should be `$_POST['user']`